# Simple program to create moveable "cards" on static background?

Tags: image, drag-and-drop, game-engine, shuffle, card

I am an educational content developer converting traditional lessons and materials into online activities. I make videos showing these materials being moved around a table or board, and need a way for them to practice at home.

In the past, I've just made each card/etc on a Google Slide and set it up for kids to manipulate, but that can lead accidentally stretching or deleting something (or just playing around).

What I need:

1. Import images.
2. Set one image as background
3. Set other images as cards that can be clicked and dragged on background.
4. Ideally, set specific areas where different card can be placed.
5. Place starting cards in stacks (ideally, either in specific order or shuffled)
6. Return cards to original stacks with one click.
7. Ideally, cards on which users can write their own text and/or import picture.

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Stencyl seems totally capable but can do more so the tutorials aren't focused on something so simple. Dulst is built for cards specifically, but it seems more oriented to a Pokemon-style attack-your-enemy's-cards game.

Comment: Well, there's https://deck.of.cards/ which is ... well .. cards.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer, is there some way to add your own images and control the number of cards in the deck?

Comment: It's an open source project, so you can do whatever you like.

Comment: Hmm... Is this not the best place to seek help as a complete noob?

Comment: This is a great place to get help solving a specific coding issue -- not really the best place to get spoonfed exactly what you want.